# scala add Object to Seq[Future[Model]] and wait until finished to return

Tags: scala, playframework

Hi in my scala application I want to return a Seq[Model] to my Frontend.

```
def getContentComponentUsageSearch: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request =>
    println(request.body.asJson)
    request.body.asJson.map(_.validate[StepIds] match {
      case JsSuccess(stepIds, _) =>

        println("VALIDE SUCCESS -------------------------------")

        var templates: Seq[Future[Option[ProcessTemplatesModel]]] = Future.sequence(stepIds.s.map(s => {
          processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplate(s.processStep_id).flatMap(stepTemplate => {
            templates :+ processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(stepTemplate.get.processTemplate_id.get)
          })
        }))

        templates.map(done => {
          Future.sequence(templates).map(a => {
            Ok(Json.obj("id" -> a))
          })
        })




      case JsError(_) =>
        println("NOT VALID -------------------------------")
        Future.successful(BadRequest("Process Template not create client"))
      case _ => Future.successful(BadRequest("Process Template create client"))
    }).getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest("Process Template create client")))
  }
```

I need to wait until its finished and return then. What would be a good way to achieve this?

thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

at the moment I try this:

```
 val fList: List[Future[ProcessTemplatesModel]] +: stepIds.s.map(s => {
             processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplate(s.processStep_id).map(stepTemplate => {
              processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(stepTemplate.get.processTemplate_id.get).map(a => {
                a.get
              })
            })
          })

        Future.successful( Ok(Json.obj("id" -> fList)))
```

Issue in this case is the `+:` I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only have to rewrite this part:

```
templates.map(done => {
          Future.sequence(templates).map(a => {
            Ok(Json.obj("id" -> a))
          })
        })
```

If you would do something like this:

```
val futSeqOpt: Future[Seq[Option[ProcessTemplatesModel]]] = Future.sequence(templates)
val futSeq: Future[Seq[ProcessTemplatesModel]] = futSeqOpt.map(_.getOrElse("defaultValue"))

futSeq.map(seq => Ok(Json.toJson(seq)))
```

it should work. (I only added the types for demonstration).

Comment: compare the types! it must be `Future[List[ProcessTemplatesModel]]`. Then you can map it to `futSeq.map(fList => Ok(Json.obj("id" -> fList)))`

Comment: ah I expected `templates` was correct. The correct implementation is hard without the domain model knowledge.